# installing pg_repack fails with pgut/pgut.h:13:10: fatal error: c.h: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, pg-repack

In am installing pg_repack with

"sudo pgxn install pg_repack" and it end

```
INFO: best version: pg_repack 1.4.7
INFO: saving /tmp/tmp7qn9rttz/pg_repack-1.4.7.zip
INFO: unpacking: /tmp/tmp7qn9rttz/pg_repack-1.4.7.zip
INFO: building extension
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmp7qn9rttz/pg_repack-1.4.7/bin'
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -I/usr/include/postgresql -DREPACK_VERSION=1.4.7 -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o pg_repack.o pg_repack.c
In file included from pgut/pgut-fe.h:13,
                 from pg_repack.c:25:
pgut/pgut.h:13:10: fatal error: c.h: No such file or directory
   13 | #include "c.h"
      |          ^~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: pg_repack.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmp7qn9rttz/pg_repack-1.4.7/bin'
make: *** [Makefile:35: all] Error 2
ERROR: command returned 2: make PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config all
```

Even downloading the pg_repack [source](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) and build with make has the same error.

Comment: You probably didn't install the PostgreSQL headers.

Comment: are you referring to install postgresql-server-dev-12

Comment: Sounds right. I have no Debian here